# How to seperate a string with only '=' in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having a problem with splitting a `string` into 2 different strings seperated by the '`=`' `char`.
The For command is default seperating by spaces ' '. How can i make it not do that?

Code example

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= = NOT SPACE" %%a in ("%~1") do set argument=%%a & set value=%%b
```

The string i would like to seperate:

```
ASentence = This is a sentence
```

What i get from above is `ASentence` and `This`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ("%~1") do set argument=%%a & set value=%%b
```

Note : the trailing space in `argument` (%%a) and leading in `value` (%%b) can be removed by using

```
set "argument=%argument:~0,-1%"
set "value=%value:~1%"
```

Note: `tokens=1,2` would also work in this case if the value assigned to `value` (%%b) does **not** contain `=`.